# Use the name of a column as an input of a function Python

Tags: python, string, function, group-by

I am trying to optimize my code by using functions. Right now, I have a large code and the "groupby" function is used quite a lot. I am trying to use groupby inside my function but one of the inputs must be one of the dataframes columns:
I have a dataframe that contains different users IDs, meal times, and different glucose values in different times. I want to take  ONLY the value of glucose in t_0 (the closest sample to the meal_time) and for that purpose, I created a column called "difference" that shows the difference between the meal time and the measured time, so for obtaining glucose in t_0, I just have to do:

```
df_t0 = df.groupby(['user_id','meal_time'],as_index=False).difference.min().reset_index(name=reset_index)
```

As I said before, I have done plenty of groupbys during the code and the name of the column (difference) was not always the same.

When doing the function, I tried doing:

```
def make_ff (self,gb1,gb2,gb3,what,reset_index):

    if what=='size':
        ff=self.groupby([gb1,gb2]).size().reset_index(name=reset_index)
    elif what=='min':
        ff=self.groupby([gb1,gb2]).gb3.min().reset_index(name=reset_index)
    elif what=='max':
        ff=self.groupby([gb1,gb2]).gb3.max().reset_index(name=reset_index)
    else:
        ff=self.groupby([gb1,gb2]).gb3.mean().reset_index(name=reset_index)
    return ff
```

And when I call the function, I do it this way:

```
df_t0 =make_ff(cg,'user_id','meal_time','difference','min','difference','No')
```

I get the following error:

```
'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'gb3'
```

I have also tried using eval(gb3) but I just cannot solve the problem.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use `.gb3`, use `[gb3]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try using *args or **kwargs in function definition.

While calling, wrap all groupby's in a dictionary and call **groupby_dict.

It's packing and unpacking.

Comment: How does this answer the question?